# What to do if my phone is stolen?

Tags: 6.0-marshmallow, factory-reset, gmail, google, password

My phone was stolen recently.

I read that if you have a Google account connected to your phone, the thief needs to enter your Google password when wiping the data or factory resetting it.

However, after my phone was stolen, I changed my email password and remotely logged my phone out from my account.

Should I have not done this?

Comment: Google does not store the password on the device, instead it uses authorization token that can be disabled individually. Therefore instead of changing your password you should logout the stolen device using Google's Security section: https://myaccount.google.com/device-activity

Comment: I did exactly that, but my question is, now that I have done that, if thief wanted to factory reset my phone, will he be prompted with a "enter google account password"

Comment: if your device was reachable in https://www.google.com/android/devicemanager after it was stolen, the answer is yes, device is FRP locked after factory reset

Comment: Why should a thief factory reset the device? An Android 6 device is so old it has no value if you would try to sell it.

Comment: What would they do with it? Throw it in the trash?

Comment: a thief usually will try to sell EVERYTHING